# PHP global variable modifier does not work

Tags: php, function, variables, null, global

I have a file(color.php) included in my index.php. In the included file, I have defined some variables and functions.

(color.php)

```
<?php
  $colors = array(0xffffff, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x808080);
  function getColors() {
     global $colors;
     return $colors;
  }
?>
```

Below is my main file(index.php).

```
<?php
      require_once('color.php');
      class Test {
           function Test() {
               var_dump(getColors()); // returns NULL
           }
      }
?>
```

Why is it that calling the getColors() function, it returns NULL which is supposedly, will return an array of colors? Am I missing something? Or is there any config needed in php.ini? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

```
<?php
$colors = array(0xffffff, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x808080);
function getColors() {
    global $colors;
    return $colors;
}
class Test {
    function Test() {
        var_dump(getColors());
    }
}
$st = new Test();
$st->Test();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getColors() {
   return array(0xffffff, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x808080);
}
```

As to why it's returning `NULL`, there must be a good explanation.

Perhaps you call `unset($colors)` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me.  I'm not sure if you were creating a new reference to the Test class or calling the method, but this worked.

```
  $colors = array(0xffffff, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x808080);
  function getColors() {
     global $colors;
     return $colors;
  }
      class Test {
           function __construct() {
              if (getColors() == NULL) {
                echo "null";// returns NULL
              } else {
                print_r(getColors());
              }
           }
      }

  $test = new Test();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I already figured out what caused this bug. I included the file inside one of the functions of the main class, so the statement

```
global $colors;
```

of function getColors() in the included file returns NULL because $colors was not defined outside the main class. The code I posted here was just a dummy representation of the actual code I'm having trouble with. I did not anticipate this one when I posted it. My bad. Anyway, this is fix now. Thank you guys for your answers. Till next time. :)